# Question related to hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, inference

Topps, the collectible baseball cards manufacturer, claims that each pack of cards has 10 cards. In a sample of 50 packs, it was found that there were 9.75 cards per pack. Do these results support Topps claim ? Use a level of 0.05 significance.

I came across this question on the internet. I can't figure out which statistical test to use to test this claim.

I need to know the name of this test.

Comment: Please explain what "at sounds" might mean.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typographical error. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. A lot still rests on how you interpret the claim. For instance, if we take it to mean "all our packs have exactly 10 cards," then observing 9.75 cards per pack implies two things. First, the person reporting that observation cannot do arithmetic, because it implies a total of $9.75\times 50 = 487.5$ cards, which is impossible. Second, if the real average is anything other than $10$, the claim is false--period; no statistical test is needed. One might also interpret the claim as meaning "*on average* our packs contain *at least* 10 cards." What is your interpretation?